# Find repeating values in List

Tags: recursion, f#

I want to return true if I find a repeating value in the list

```
let rec repeats L = 
   match L with
   | [] -> false
   | x::xs when x = xs.Head -> true
   | x::xs -> repeats xs;;


repeats [1;2;3;4;5]
```

Should return false. But I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The input list was empty.
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1.get_Head()
   at FSI_0003.repeats[a](FSharpList`1 L)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0004>.$FSI_0004.main@()
   at main@dm()
Stopped due to error
```

What should I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
x::xs = 5::[]
```

in the last case

You want to change it to

```
|x::xs::xss when x=xs -> true
```

Comment: Edited my question to match the changed code. But I still get an error

Comment: Remove the second case block (`| x::xs when x = xs.Head -> true`)

Comment: @jth41 - Try not to edit the code in the question.  It is best to leave it as is, or add something afterwards to make it clear that your code has changed